# Why does str.split(" " or ", ") not give an Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) takes only one optional argument as a delimiter. However, if I construct an expression like the following:

```py
"Hello, you there".split(" " or ", ")
```

It seems to disregard the second option silently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is not passing two arguments, but instead an **expression**. Every expression gets evaluated to a *value* before that value is passed to the function.

That means that only **one value** remains after the expression inside the brackets has been computed. Now, in the above case that's a bit tricky, because it appears that it's nothing - while it's actually a *whitespace* character. `or` picks the *first* of the two string values compared:

```py
print(" " or ", ")
```

So `" " or ", "` gets computed **at first** - then the **result** of this computation (`" "`) gets passed as an argument to `split()`.

In the end, a **single argument** gets passed - that's why Python is not complaining with an Error. You're interacting with `split()` just as you're meant to: passing one argument as the separator to consider.

In short, these two expressions are equivalent:

```py
"Hello, you there".split(" " or ", ") == "Hello, you there".split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

**str.split(seperation or delimeter, maxsplit**),
 this function passes only one arguement as a delimeter and a maximum split, as you are passing two arguemnts as an delimeter and it is not showing any error because it comes under exception in python.

You have given a whitespace as a first arguement it executes that only.